# Cannot read property '0' of undefined help me plese

Tags: reactjs

I need help please, and in my console i get this message:TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'



function Course(props) {

    const courserName = props.match.params.coursername;
    const courses = {
        reactjs:[
            {title:"reactjs title 1",vid:"edblCnJhvdI"},
            {title:"reactjs title 2",vid:"MXZvQuG5mQc"},
            {title:"reactjs title 3",vid:"VPIrZr8YVrQ"}
        ],


        nodejs: [
            {title:"nodejs title 1", vid: "ngwZT1FR5Fw"},
            {title:"nodejs title 2", vid: "goOuCIv39e4"},
            {title:"nodejs title 3", vid: "https://youtu.be/r2L8ffwx9TY"}
        ]
    }

    
    const [vid, uid] = useState(courses[courserName][0].vid)
    const [title, utit] = useState(courses[courserName][0].title)

    const renderVideo = () => {
        return (
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vid + "?rel=0"} allowFullScreen></iframe>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> {courserName}  </h1>
            {renderVideo()}

            <div className="menu">
            
                {
                    courses[courserName].map(item=>{
                        return <a className="nav-link" href="#">{item.title}</a>
                    })
                }

            </div>



        </div>
    );
}
```

export default Course;

Comment: your array is empty

Comment: Is courserName the right value?

Comment: Yes courserName is value

Comment: I explain I am following a tutorial but it works for the person in the tutorial and it gives me an error. "const [vid, uid] = useState(courses[courserName][0].vid)"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the hooks should be positioned at the top level of the functional component.
The value of courseName mightn't be 'reactjs' or 'nodejs'.
Otherwise, you can set the initial value of useState as the empty string and then set the states in the useEffect function with courseName dependency.

Answer (score -1):

courses[courserName][0] is undefined because courses is an object, not an array